# Good Fast Way to Let Users Visualize and Explore Relational Data?

Tags: linq, visualization, iqueryable, relational

I'm looking for either a web-based or Windows-based way to point to a relational data source using automated schema exploration (or, even better, a reflection-based approach that would work on any IQueryable in-memory data source) and allow easy exploration of data, traversing between records in related tables, etc.  Basically a dynamic UI that doesn't have to look perfect.  Any recommended approaches?  Looking less for a rapid prototyping tool and more for a generic data explorer that can work out of the box and can work in multiple contexts against multiple data sources.

Answer (score 1):

There is an application called LinqPad that I use for a similar idea mentioned above.

[linqpad.net](http://linqpad.net/)